# Why isn't the 'confirm password and password' the same part working?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Why isn't the '**confirm password and password the same**' part working? Meaning, the part that uses the '*getElementById*' to adress the password and confirmpassword. Every part works but that particular part. It doesn't show a red box around the text fields. Can anyone help me?

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <script>
    function submitinfo()
    {
    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var confirmpassword = document.getElementById("confirmpassword").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

    if(firstname !== "" && document.getElementById("firstname").style.borderColor == "red")
        {
        document.getElementById("firstname").style.border = "none"
        }

    if(lastname !== "" && document.getElementById("lastname").style.borderColor == "red")
        {
        document.getElementById("lastname").style.border = "none"
        }

    if(username !== "" && document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor == "red")
        {
        document.getElementById("username").style.border = "none"
        }

    if(password !== "" && document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor == "red")
        {
        document.getElementById("password").style.border = "none"
        }

    if(confirmpassword !== "" && document.getElementById("confirmpassword").style.borderColor == "red")
        {
        document.getElementById("confirmpassword").style.border = "none"
        }

    if(email !== "" && document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor == "red")
        {
        document.getElementById("email").style.border = "none"
        }

    if(firstname == "")
        {
        document.getElementById("firstname").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("firstname").style.borderStyle = "solid";
        }

    if(lastname == "")
        {
        document.getElementById("lastname").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("lastname").style.borderStyle = "solid";
        }

    if(username == "")
        {
        document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("username").style.borderStyle = "solid";
        }

    if(password == "")
        {
        document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("password").style.borderStyle = "solid";
        }

    if(confirmpassword == "")
        {
        document.getElementById("confirmpassword").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("confirmpassword").style.borderStyle = "solid";
        }

    if(email == "")
        {
        document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("email").style.borderStyle = "solid";
        } 


    if(password !== "" && confirmpassword !== "" && document.getElementById("password").style.border == "none" && document.getElementById("confirmpassword").style.border == "none" && password !== confirmpassword) { document.getElementById("password").style.border = "red"; document.getElementById("confirmpassword").style.border = "red"; }

    if(firstname && lastname && username && password && confirmpassword && email !== "")
        {
        window.open()
        }
    }
    </script>
    <h><font size=4 color=3BCCBE><b>Full Name</b></font><h/>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" size="15px" placeholder="First">
    <input type="text" id="lastname" size="15px" placeholder="Last">
    <br> <br> <br> <br>
    <h><font size=4 color=3BCCBE><b>Choose your username</b></font></h>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="username" size="37px">
    <br>
    <p><font size=3 color="grey">atleast 6 characters long</font></p>
    <br>
    <h><font size=4 color=3BCCBE><b>Create a password</b></font></h>
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="password" size="37px"> 
    <br> <br> <br> <br>
    <h><font size=4 color=3BCCBE><b>Confirm your password</b></font><h/>
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="confirmpassword" size="37px">
    <br> <br> <br> <br>
    <h><font size=4 color=3BCCBE><b>Email address</b></font><h/>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="email" size="37px">
    <br> <br> <br> <br>

    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitinfo()" style="height:50px; width:85px; font-size:22px;>
    <br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's always helpful to create a jsfiddle demo in such cases: http://jsfiddle.net/h2WJq/.

Answer (score 1):

You left out the

```
document.getElementById("password").style.borderStyle = "solid";
```

and

```
document.getElementById("confirmpassword").style.borderStyle = "solid";
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting `borderWidth`? Not very clear if it is set or not. If not, you should set to 1 pixel for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple set your standard border using `style.border` and try to make it more dynamic if it's always the same configuration, look:

```
var border_style = "1px solid red";
document.getElementById("password").style.border = border_style;
document.getElementById("confirmpassword").style.border = border_style;
```